# Angular debounce blocks modifications from javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the controller (truncated for this example):

```
app.controller('QuickNotesCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.notes = [];

    $scope.onEnter = function(event) {
        if (event.key === "Enter") {
            $scope.addNote();
        }
    };

    $scope.addNote = function () {
        $scope.notes.push({
            text: '',
        });
    };
}]);
```

And HTML:

```html
<input type="text"
       ng-model="note.text"
       ng-model-options="{debounce: 500}"
       ng-keyup="onEnter($event)"
/>
```

When someone types quickly a[ENTER]a the onEnter() is triggered and then addNote() is called but nothing is added to $scope.notes. When someone types a[ENTER]a slowly everything works fine. When I decrease the debounce to 200 for most cases the [ENTER] key is handled properly but this is not a solution because the notes are stored in backend and for good performance debounce cannot be set to lower value than 500. So the question is: how to allow $scope.notes.push() to work without decreasing debounce below 500? I'm stuck in this case on Angular 1.6.

Comment: mind the tags, this is an angularjs question, not angular.

Comment: What you are trying is not supported by built-in Angularjs directives -- there is no separate debounce setting for 'Enter' key. For blur there is one:
    ng-model-options="{updateOn: 'default blur', debounce: { 'default': 500, 'blur': 0 }}"